# Long Java processing causes error in Flex

Tags: java, apache-flex, jakarta-ee, adobe, amf

I have a Web Application (Java + Flex) where I upload a csv file with a large number of rows, and process it and insert in database. It takes more than one hour to finish processing, but Flex gives me this error:

```
[RPC Fault faultString="error" faultCode="Channel.Call.Failed" faultDetail="NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed"]
at mx.rpc::AbstractInvoker/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::faultHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AbstractInvoker.as:220]
at mx.rpc::Responder/fault()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\Responder.as:53]
at mx.rpc::AsyncRequest/fault()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\rpc\AsyncRequest.as:103]
at NetConnectionMessageResponder/channelFaultHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\channels\NetConnectionChannel.as:669]
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
at mx.messaging.channels::AMFChannel/statusHandler()[C:\autobuild\3.2.0\frameworks\projects\rpc\src\mx\messaging\channels\AMFChannel.as:365]
```

Can you guys help me with it? It takes about 1 hour to show, and the file keeps processing on server.

Thanks!

Comment: Flex will give you that error as soon as your server returns a timeout response (which should be after a few seconds). I think you should simply be able to listen for the Fault Event and swallow it. (Bit curious though: what the hell are you doing that takes an hour to process? Rendering a 3D movie based on that CSV data?)

Comment: This definitely sounds like a situation where the request should be started (and return that it's started), and the application periodically poll for the status; or some form of messaging system (like WebSockets, Comet, or GraniteDS's Gravity) for the server to post messages back to the client when processing is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use server-based Java remoting and web messaging technology like BlazeDS or GraniteDS to make it work, that will help you to connect to back-end distributed data and push data to Adobe Flex.

For GraniteDS more information can be obtained form:

```
http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229378
```

and for BlazeDS follow the link:

```
http://www.adobe.com/aboutadobe/pressroom/pressreleases/200712/121307BlazeDS.html
```